# How do you remove markdown when using strip_html for meta description in Jekyll?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

i'm trying to use the following code to generate my meta description tag

```
<meta name="description" content="{{ page.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 50 }}">
```

but this is what's displayed

```
##Sending Several Documents to a Group## Using online storage accounts like [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com)
```

is there a way to also strip markdown tags?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do a :

```
<meta name="description" 
content="{{ page.content | markdownify | strip_html | truncatewords: 50 }}">
```

But it will only works with `md/markdown` files, not html. And this will not render `Liquid tags`.

The solution can be to set a `description: foo bar` in the page/post front matter and get it in `_includes/head.html` with a :

```
{% if page.description %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ page.description }}">
{% else %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ site.description }}">
{% endif %}
```